# Find points on curve where tangent is horizontal

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

I've looked for a similar question on here but couldn't find any. I have found a similar question on Google but it still didn't help me.

My question is

> Find the points on the curve y = cos(x)/(2+sin(x)) at which the tangent is horizontal.

I know that it's horizontal when f'(x) = 0
but I can't seem to work out the x values.

My f'(x) I worked out to be (-sin(x)))/(2) - (cos(x)cos(x))/((2+sin(x))^2)

How can I find the x values when I sub x = 0, I cant equate it to 0

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{2+\sin x}.
$$
Then,
$$
f^{\prime}(x)=-\frac{2\sin x+1}{\left(\sin x+2\right)^{2}}.
$$
Note that $f^{\prime}(x)=0$ if and only if 
$$
2\sin x+1=0.
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: So 2sin(x) = -1,
     sin(x) = -1/2,
     x=arcsin(-0.5)

Comment: Is that right? @Par

Comment: Yes, or more explicitly, $(2n-1/6)\pi$ where $n$ is an integer. See also http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BCos%5Bx%5D%2F(2%2BSin%5Bx%5D)%5D%3D0